# How to call an R function in a particular R package from Rcpp

Tags: r, rcpp

I am wondering if there is a way to call an R function in a particular package from Rcpp. For example, I would like to call "dtrunc" function in "truncdist" package in my Rcpp file. Is it possible to do that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can use an R function within Rcpp.

```
library(inline)

src <- '
  using namespace Rcpp;
  Environment truncdist("package:truncdist");
  Function dtrunc = truncdist["dtrunc"];

  NumericVector res = dtrunc(x, "norm", 1, 2);
  return res;
'
x <- seq( 0, 3, .1 )

fun <- cxxfunction(signature(x="numeric"),src, plugin="Rcpp")
identical(fun(x), dtrunc( x, spec="norm", a=1, b=2 ))
```

As a note, you need to keep in mind that the performance of `dtrunc` will not improve simply by being inside Rcpp.  It will essentially be the exact same speed as if you called it directly in R.

Comment: Even slower because `Rcpp` wraps it in a convoluted `tryCatch` call.

Answer (score 5):

Sure. You'd grab the function like this:

```
Environment truncdist("package:truncdist") ;
Function dtrunc = truncdist["dtrunc"] ;
```

Or even this with version 0.11.5

```
Function dtrunc( "dtrunc", "truncdist" ) ;
```